# Adding Advance Custom Field field in Genesis Framework template

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, genesis

What can I do in order to add an ACF `textarea` into a Genesis child theme template.

I tried a lot but did not find any way.

Thank you.

Comment: OK, you tried a lot, please tell us what you tried with samples of code so we can see what are you doing and how we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to figure out where you want to put the field.  You can either use one of the genesis hooks ([see here](http://genesistutorials.com/visual-hook-guide/)) or perhaps your modifying a theme field directly in which case you can just paste the code whereever you want.

For example if you're using a hook and you want to put it in your header, you could do something like:

```
add_action('genesis_header', 'add_content_to_header');
function add_content_to_header() {
    echo get_field('my_textarea_field');';
}
```

Or do put it directly into a child theme template file, just put this whereever you want:

```
the_field('my_textarea_field');';
```

Comment: Thank you help but i have already sort out how to do this but now i am facing a new problem. How i can put shortcode using advance custom field's field

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you're asking.  Does the custom field contain a shortcode?  And you want to run whatever shortcode is in that field?  If so you would just use echo do_shortcode( get_field('my_textarea_field') )